# How to program graphical interface being blind?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, accessibility

This is a translation from the same [question in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274100/c%C3%B3mo-programar-interfaz-gr%C3%A1fica-siendo-ciego), and I'm posting it here since I think you could provide more information than our small community.

I am blind from birth and I am studying the career of systems engineering at the university.

I would like to know how I can program the graphical interface of an application in Android Studio. I have searched for tutorials and found several that, for example, to add a button, drag it to the place where you want it to be and it is automatically added to it.

In my case, by not seeing, this is impossible since my screen reader is not qualified to do that kind of work. So my question is **how could I do to program android graphical interfaces without seeing?**

Comment: Just edit the XML layout files directly, I assume you have a screen reader that can handle this. The graphical layout editor is simply producing regular XML files.

Comment: Thank you, sir, that's what we've suggested to him, it seems too verbose and sounds like a lot to memorize, hope someone can have some trick, IDK... perhaps something like an XSLT based solution or a way to create the GUI programmatically or perhaps with an HTML like [tag:dukescript] does. I'm just guessing hope some expert can suggest a more efficient way to code.

Comment: @RuslanLópez there's no other way to make layouts in Android Studio without XML. Plus, I've had experience learning XML for Android. I can provide some Udacity courses (unfortunately in English) for you to learn.

Comment: @Divergence actually you should check the link, I don't want to get into technicisms, The idea is to develop without creating the xml by hand.

Comment: @RuslanLópez I checked the link, but currently, there is no way make layouts/drawables/resource files without XML.

Comment: then you should have found that the development is done without xml , that's the goal ;)

Comment: Actually, there are little parts (LinearLayout? RelativeLayout? CardView? android namespace?) that android developed for and only for XML.

Comment: so again you don't have to create the whole xml, and that's the objective

Answer (score 1):

You can code your layouts in XML.
Writing in XML gives you the full control on how you want to code your layouts.
I'm also Visually Impaired and I'm coding layouts in XML since many years.
There's a good tutorial at tutorialpoint which can help you in this. Also, I'm pasting one of the xml code sample of a layout from my app for your reference. You can find the code below the link:
Tutorial:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_user_interface_layouts

XML Layout Sample:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_create_theme" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```